# Можно ли предотвратить инкремент Identity при неудачных вставках?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Например, есть таблица, где на колонке стоит Identity.

Если первая вставка была удачной, а следующие 10 были недуачными, то при последующей вставке записи будут иметь такой Identity:

1

11

Как видно, после 1 идет сразу 11.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77891/prevent-gaps-while-using-identity-sequence-object-in-sql-server

Comment: @MaxU, хм... А разве объект очереди есть в 2008?

Comment: [Судя по доке появилось как раз в SQL Server 2008](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-queue-transact-sql): `SQL Server (starting with 2008)`

Comment: Вопрос в том, зачем это вообще делать. Архитектура БД должна строится так, что бы дыры в нумерации id ни на что не влияли. Потому как вне зависимости от того, как вы будете вставлять записи со временем дыры появятся, ходя бы при удалении записей

Comment: @Mike кроме переполнения int

Comment: @Alex78191 то же верно, но можно сразу сделать колонку bigint ее будет сложно переполнить